# How to compile SQLite for Android with SEE support?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to compile SQLite library for Android with encryption extension enabled.

In the official guide [here](http://www.sqlite.org/android/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) it says

`To use the SQLite Encryption Extension (SEE) on Android, replace the sqlite3.c file at "jni/sqlite/sqlite3.c" with a SEE-enabled version (i.e. the concatenation of sqlite3.c and see.c.`

I cannot find the `see.c` file anywhere in the [SQLite source code.](http://www.sqlite.org/snapshot/sqlite-amalgamation-201504011321.zip)

How can I compile with SEE support ? Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the download link [here](http://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki). It says

> Some of the documentation on this website is open to viewing by the
>   general public. However, access to the SEE source code requires a
>   username and password, which is available only to licensees.

Comment: So is it necessary to buy a SEE license to view the source code?